# Official name of the problem of sum of edge squares of a graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$, a $1-1$ mapping $f:V\rightarrow\{1,2,...,n\}$ is called a proper numbering of G. Then we know, for a proper mapping $f$, the edgesum of the $s_f(G)$ produced by $f$ is defined as 
\begin{equation}
s_f(G)=\sum_{uv\in E}|f(u)-f(v)|.
\end{equation}
The edgesum $s(G)$ of a graph $G$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
s(G) = min\{s_f(G): \mathrm{f\ is\ a\ proper\ numbering\ of\ G}\}.
\end{equation}

Then consider a function as the sum of square of edges of $G$ with a given $f$,i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{uv\in E}|f(u)-f(v)|^2.
\end{equation}
Is there any name of the minimization problem of this function in mathematics? Or is there any results when $G$ is a path or a cycle, or a Cartesian product of paths or cycles?